# What is the best recommendation for analyzing 4 data sets, each with 10 observations at 10 times?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test, friedman-test

Four samples were analyzed daily for 5 days. It is known that time influences the values of the analyses, because the samples are sensitive to the passage of time. Here is a table illustrating the results of this experiment:

| **Days** | **Sample 1** | **Sample 2** | **Sample 3** | **Sample 4** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Day 1 | 2,7 | 6,6 | 2,3 | 2,1 |
| Day 2 | 3,2 | 9,0 | 2,2 | 2,2 |
| Day 3 | 3,3 | 10,4 | 1,9 | 2,1 |
| Day 4 | 4,1 | 13,5 | 2,6 | 2,2 |
| Day 5 | 4,7 | 14,8 | 2,1 | 2,3 |

I am in doubt between Friedman's test, which I believe by considering the order of the data could be useful for analyzing the experiment where each passing day is important. On the other hand, there is the Kruskal-Wallis test that can also be used. My statistical knowledge is not advanced and I do not know which test is more appropriate to analyze this experiment.